# How can I pass a row as parameter to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get information of a row to show in a tooltip. For example:

```
<html>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td onmouseover="loadtooltip(parameter)">Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td onmouseover="loadtooltip(parameter)">Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<html>
```

So, when I pass the mouse over the row I need the content of the others columns.

Thx in advance.

Comment: "I want to get information of a row" what information? Do you want a reference to the row?

Comment: You should set position: relative; for your onhover td. Then in this td via loadtooltip function you should add tooltip html and set style for showing it

Comment: Just the text of the others columns. I need to apply some math at the values to display in the tooltip.

Comment: @LucasBastos: "Just the text of the others columns", so then you don't actually need the row, you need the sibling `td`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged your question with jQuery, so I'm assuming a jQuery solution is acceptable. First, don't inline your event handlers, it's bad form. Instead hook up your event handlers using `.on`. I added a class to make identifying the `td` you want to attach the roll over to a little easier. Then in the handler, `this` will refer to the element that recieved the event and you can use `$(this).parent()` to get it's parent `tr`.

```js
$("td.rollable").on("mouseover", function(e) {
  var row = $(this).parent();
  alert(row[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td class="rollable">Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td class="rollable">Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<html>
```

**Edit:** since your comment suggests you actually need the siblings and not the row itself

```js
$("td.rollable").on("mouseover", function(e) {
  var siblings = $(this).siblings();
  var text = siblings.map(function(i, item) { return item.innerHTML; });
  alert($.makeArray(text).join(", "));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td class="rollable">Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td class="rollable">Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `parentNode` variable as:

```
<td onmouseover="loadtooltip(this.parentNode)">Smith</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#table").find("tr").eq(0)
```

To get the row at index 0. Then you can loop through td elements.

Comment: And how would you know which td is the right one?